# For Riemann integral partitions, does it matter whether $f$ is evaluated at a point in $(t_{i-1},t_i)$ or $[t_{i-1},t_i]$?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

> **Definition** $:$ Let $F$ be a Banach space. A function $f : [a,b] \longrightarrow F$ is said to be Riemann integrable if there exists $\int_{a}^{b} f \in F$ such that for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that for any partition $\mathfrak P = \{a = t_0 \lt t_1 \lt t_2 \lt \cdots \lt t_n = b \}$ with $\left \|\mathfrak P \right \| \lt \delta$ and for any choice of $\xi_i \in (t_{i-1},t_i),$ for $i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$ we have $$\left \|\int_{a}^{b} f - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f(\xi_i) (t_i - t_{i-1}) \right \|_{F} \lt \varepsilon.$$ In this case we say that $\displaystyle {\int_{a}^{b} f}$ is the Riemann integral of $f$ on $[a,b].$

Now my question is as follows $:$

In the above definition of Riemann integral will it make any difference if instead of $\xi_i \in (t_{i-1},t_i)$ we stipulate $\xi_i \in [t_{i-1},t_i]\ $? Any suggestion in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One issue might be that without this restriction, there is nothing stopping the $\xi_i$ values from being non-distinct -- two successive ones could be equal. This might be more of an annoying edge case more than anything else.

Comment: @jwimberley what's the problem then? For defining Darboux sums we are allowing closed sub-intervals determined by the partition. Right? Riemann sums are always lying in between the upper and lower Darboux sums. As we go on refining the partition the upper and lower sum get almost clustered together. So by refining the partition properly we can decrease the distance between upper and lower Darboux sum and the distance between the Riemann integral and any of the sums. So by triangle inequality we are through.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's a problem, but just that changing the definition to a closed bound is, if anything, tightening the definition by requiring someone to prove extra cases where there are non-distinct $\xi_i$ bounds and the like. (The definition does not say that $f$ is integrable if *and only if* these conditions are met). If, as seems clear, there's no difference, why bother specifying a tighter definition when a looser one will do?

Comment: BTW, is there a missing condition in the definition about $\delta$ and the width of each interval?

Comment: Fixed it now. Thanks for pointing that out @jwimberley.

Comment: I briefly thought there was a good reason for the restriction due to integrable singularities at $a$ or $b$, but of course the definition of Riemann integrability doesn't include such cases (which is why $f$ is required to be defined on the interval $[a,b]$).

Comment: I guess it makes no difference as if $\xi_i$ happens to be a point of one partition there exists another partition where one moves the point slightly. The move can be made infinitesimally small, and the finite sum is continuous w.r.t. such moves.

Comment: I have tried to improve the title. "Doubt about Riemann integrals" is uselessly broad.

Answer (score 2):

It does not hurt anything to allow for $\xi$ to be in closed subintervals. A kind of manual way to see this is to connect the Riemann sum on a tagged partition with tags at endpoints to a Riemann sum on a tagged partition without tags at endpoints. One way to do that is to split into two cases depending on whether two neighboring $\xi$'s are the same or not.

If they are the same, merge those two subintervals; doing this all over results in a partition with mesh $2\delta$ which still goes to zero, and the Riemann sum on this tagged partition is exactly the same as the Riemann sum you already had.

If they are not the same, enlarge the subinterval which had $\xi$ at the endpoint by a little bit, at the expense of its neighbor. As long as the sum of all the enlargement lengths is less than $\varepsilon/4M$ where $M$ is the bound on $f$, the resulting change in the Riemann sum will be less than $\varepsilon$.